# Operators execution order

Tags: javascript

I try to evaluate expression in terms of operators precedence and got quite confusing result.

Here is expression: a.b(c).d(e,f).

It is consist of  member access and function call operators.
According to [MDN OperatorPrecedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)
member access operator have left-to-right associativity and higher precedence than function call operator.

So in above expression second member access must happened before first function call.

So what I am missing?

Comment: Yea I just read that as I have some object `a` which has a property `b`. `b` is a function which takes a parameter `c`. `b` returns an object which has a property `d` which is a function and takes two parameters `e` and `f`. And that all goes from left to right directly since the second function `d` depends on the first function `b` completing and returning the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> member access operator have left-to-right associativity and higher precedence than function call operator.

That just means that `a.b(c)` is evaluated as `(a.b)(c)`, not `a.(b(c))` (which isn't valid anyway).

> So in above expression second member access must happened before first function cal

How could that be? `foo().bar` means to access the property `bar` of the **return value** of the function call. Which property should be accessed if the that had to happen *before* the call?

Or in your example, on which object should `.d` be accessed? `a`? `a.b`?

Comment: If descry above expression as ( A op1 B op2 C op1 D op2 E,F ) all op1 must happend before op2.
As I said i use operator precedence rule and got some nonsense. So i use rule wrong, but what is wrong?

Comment: That's incorrect, since a function call is not a binary operator (personally I wouldn't even call it an operator). So you'd rather have to write it as `A op1 B op2 op1 D op2`. Now, for the second `op1` to be evaluated, the left hand side, `A op1 B op2` has to be evaluated first.

Comment: Thanks! This explanation and raina77ow mention that operator precedence is about grouping not evaluation order clarified the point.